# Windows Forms event for any action performed on the form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Is there a "generic" event for a Windows Form that will trigger any time the user clicks anything on a form? I need to make sure that a certain text box has input focus at all times, so if the user clicks on a button (or anything else, for that matter), the input focus needs to be redirected to this text box.

Is there an event in the `Form` class that will handle this, or do I have to handle a `Click` event to all controls recursively on the form?

I did some digging but I can't find what I want so far.

Comment: There is no such event that triggers any action in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured something out - every time the `TextBox` loses focus, just refocus it.

```
textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Is it that you want focus all time in the `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the question